# Reporting Services calling subreports

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

I have a main report and 30 subreports under that report. I don't want to see all of the subs every time I call the main report, I only want to see the subreports that were selected in the application.

How do I only show selected subreports?

Comment: Go to Subreport Properties, Choose "Visibility" on the left side and choose "Show or hide based on an expression". There you can write an expression which returns `true`to hide the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

The [comment from Martin K.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265301/reporting-services-calling-subreports#comment37486955_24265301) is correct if you're only concerned about the display of the sub-reports. You can set the visibility property via an expression meaning it can also be controlled by the result set or a parameter.

However, the real issue is that even though the sub-reports are hidden they are still run. This is because SSRS retrieves all of the data for the report before it finalizes the rendering. There are a number of good options discussed in [this TechNet posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/48568d60-6a70-46a7-bf5e-69a235bc80de/how-do-i-conditionally-prevent-a-subreport-from-running). But basically it boils down to two options:

### Parameters & WHERE clause filtering

You can set a hidden parameter on the sub-reports and modify the WHERE clause so that the SQL will not actually return any rows when the parameter isn't set to true. This won't stop the report rendering actions but it will stop the SQL commands from having much of an effect on the server.

Just setup a parameter on your sub-report named `@ShowSubreport` and use filtering similar to the following

```
WHERE @ShowSubReport=1
```

### Report Definition Customization Extensions (RDCE)

I haven't actually used these but it sounds quite handy, but it isn't exactly simple or easy. Report definition customization extensions allow you to programatically alter a report definition file on the fly. It takes an RDL as input and outputs an altered RDL stream. You can read more about it in the MSDN article : [What's New in Report Server Programmability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281022.aspx)